# Substitution of formula in propositional logic.

Tags: logic, induction, propositional-calculus

I have a question about something in the book "Mathematical logic for Computer Science". I will post something from the book, where I have highlighted what I do not understand, after I have posted the picture I will ask my question:

[image]

My question is regarding the induction part. What will happen if you have the situation in the picture below:

[image]

Here $d=1$, but in the subtree to the right $d$ is also $1$? Have I misunderstood something, or how to we get the induction step to work in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your above example picture is covered by the case where $B=B_1 ~op~ B_2$ of your above referenced induction proof on the depth and they share the same depth as 2. You're right the $A$ in the subtree to the right has $d=1$, and by IH this subtree can be called $B_2$. The higher $A$ can be called $B_1$. Then the inductive step says the whole tree is equivalent by substitution of your $A$ for some other logically equivalent formula $A'$ by the definition of valuation on the Boolean operator $op$ in your case. I don't see any issue here...

Comment: Thank you, I think I misunderstood, I thought that $d=1$, but it seems $d=2$.